# It's perfect vs it would be perfect

Tags: modal-verbs

Please tell me which one is correct and why?

> 1. "I want to make sure it's perfect"
> 2. "I want to make sure it would be perfect"

Comment: And what *is* the situation you're talking about? Could you provide us with the context?

Comment: I see no reason to use **would** here. Generally, "one makes sure x is y". If you are making sure of something, how could "would" apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seldom come across the phrase *make sure* taking any other form of a verb. It has been always the base verb.

> Make sure that ***it's perfect.*** 
>  Make sure that ***he attends the class.*** 
>  and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the action stage of making it, you would want to make it perfect.  If you are in the planning stages of making it, you would want to make sure it would be perfect.